# unmappable character (0xC2) for encoding US-ASCII

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I am practicing on of methods of ArrayList set().I got very crazy result here: [image]
How to escape this error and successfully to set new value for ArrayList?

I expected this output : [Forever Garcinia Plus®, Gel Aloe Vera, Hello, Forever Viber]Hello, World! , as after word Plust it should be symbol R.

Actually resulted this one:

```
/tmp/SrUvRBAjDt/HelloWorld.java:12: error: unmappable character (0xC2) for encoding US-ASCII
        list.set(0,"Forever Garcinia Plus??");
                                         ^
/tmp/SrUvRBAjDt/HelloWorld.java:12: error: unmappable character (0xAE) for encoding US-ASCII
        list.set(0,"Forever Garcinia Plus??");
                                      ^
```

2 errors

Comment: It's about [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). See this [great blog post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) which explains in detail what it's all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a Unicode character within a `String`, you can use it's decimal or hexadecimal code, and cast it to a `char`.

The `Registered trademark symbol` is code U+00AE.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol

```java
list.set(0, "Forever Garcinia Plus" + (char) 0xae);
```

Additionally, you can use the `\u` escape sequence, for a `char` literal.
Note, a `\u` escape sequence requires 4 hexadecimal values, 0 padded.

```java
list.set(0, "Forever Garcinia Plus" + '\u00ae');
```

Which, ultimately can be reduced to

```java
list.set(0, "Forever Garcinia Plus\u00ae");
```